# what happens to tweaks after upgrade from luna to freya

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, updates, cerbere

I recently upgraded from Luna to Freya. I formatted my 20GB `root` partition, but I kept my 80GB `/home` partition.

I had elementary tweaks installed and I was running `super-wingpanel` instead of the default `wingpanel`. When I upgraded to Freya, I no longer had `elementary-tweaks` installed, but for some reason, my system was still trying to run `super-wingpanel` which resulted in frustration because now I had no `wingpanel` at all.

I solved the problem by installing tweaks for Freya and then under Cerbere, I removed the `super-wingpanel` entry and added an entry for `wingpanel`.

Why did these settings persist from my Luna installation to my clean install of Freya? Is there a way to fix Cerbere without installing the Freya tweaks ppa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a reminder/disclaimer elementary tweaks has never been supported by the elementary OS developers (for reasons like this). These settings persisted because elementary tweaks modified ***user*** settings (not system settings) and since you kept your `/home` partition intact the settings were not overwritten.

All your user settings are stored in a GSettings file located in `~/.config/dconf/user`. If you wanted to completely reset all of your user settings, you *could* rename this file and start from a blank slate. However, I would not recommend doing so. If you wanted to just change the Cerbere setting, you could have reset it to the default by running the following command:

```
gsettings reset org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere monitored-processes
```